# how to run android application in mobile view?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

i am new to android, i configured all tings and developed small helloworld application, i am trying to run it launches big screen view like tablet.

I want, whenever i click run as android application android emulator should launch like mobile view . Please help me How to configure it in eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: while creating avd create there is option that build in/specify hard coded resolution .In build in selecte the option whose name starts from H...,i am not able to get complete name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Windows/Android SDK and AVD manager** and create new AVD, choose HVGA option in Built-in. If your emulator is still large, try to edit scale value when start it